# nginx configuration for PlayFramework static files

Tags: scala, nginx, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to use Nginx to server /assets folder for my Play! application. I would like to:

- Proxy most files to Play!
- Point /assets to a local folder

I am using the following configuration, but it's not working:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    upstream play_app {
        server 0.0.0.0:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://play_app;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if I get this working, will I be able to write to Nginx /assets folder from play via `Play.getFile("/assets/images")` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the play app is running on the same machine as Nginx - and is listening on port 9000

```
upstream play_app  {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
     proxy_pass  http://play_app;
  }
}
```

This will route all requests from port 80 via nginx - to the play app on the same machine on port 9000.

If you wish for NGinx to serve your local assets - add a second location before the catch all rule.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /assets {
    root /var/www;
  }
  location / {
     proxy_pass  http://play_app;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wish to add a local asset directory - simply add another location to the server

Comment: Thanks that worked. But for some reason in this configuration the server is looking for var/www/assets/assets/test.txt So if I change the root to /var/www it works but I don't want the relative path. Do you know what's missing?

Comment: So this worked: Rewrite ^/assets(.*) /$1 break;